# Set database size in odbc and snowsql?

Tags: odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I connect to snowflake via both odbc and snowsql. For whatever reason, when querying via odbc and looking at running queries in the history tab, the size is set to Large. When querying via SnowSQL the size is set to small.

I did some searching for odbc and snowsql config but could not tell if this is something I set within the UI or via the connection settings in either client.

Can I set size via a connection setting for either odbc or SnowSQL? If yes, how?

E.g. my current sanitized connection settings:

SnowSQL:
Config file:

```
[connections]
authenticator = SNOWFLAKE_JWT
private_key_path = /root/.snowsql/rsa_key.p8

[variables]
#Loads these variables on startup
#Can be used in SnowSql as select $example_variable

example_variable=27

[options]
# If set to false auto-completion will not occur interactive mode.
auto_completion = True

# going to use start and end date variables from environment in the sql script
variable_substitution = True

# main log file location. The file includes the log from SnowSQL main
# executable.
log_file = /root/.snowsql/snowsql_rt.log

# bootstrap log file location. The file includes the log from SnowSQL bootstrap
# executable.
log_bootstrap_file = /root/.snowsql/log_bootstrap

# Default log level. Possible values: "CRITICAL", "ERROR", "WARNING", "INFO"
# and "DEBUG".
log_level = DEBUG

# Timing of sql statments and table rendering.
timing = True

# Table format. Possible values: psql, plain, simple, grid, fancy_grid, pipe,
# orgtbl, rst, mediawiki, html, latex, latex_booktabs, tsv.
# Recommended: psql, fancy_grid and grid.
output_format = psql

# Keybindings: Possible values: emacs, vi.
# Emacs mode: Ctrl-A is home, Ctrl-E is end. All emacs keybindings are available in the REPL.
# When Vi mode is enabled you can use modal editing features offered by Vi in the REPL.
key_bindings = emacs

# OCSP Fail Open Mode.
# The only OCSP scenario which will lead to connection failure would be OCSP response with a
# revoked status. Any other errors or in the OCSP module will not raise an error.
# ocsp_fail_open = True

# Enable temporary credential file for Linux users
# For Linux users, since there are no OS-key-store, an unsecure temporary credential for SSO can be enabled by this option. The default value for this option is False.
# client_store_temporary_credential = True

# Repository Base URL
# The endpoint to download the SnowSQL main module.
repository_base_url = https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/snowsql
```

I use this config when connecting with the following:

```
snowsql -f ${INPUT_QUERY_FILE} \
  -o quiet=true \
  -o friendly=false \
  -o header=true \
  -o output_format=csv \
  -o output_file=output_data/data.csv \
  --accountname=${INPUT_ACCOUNT_NAME} \
  --username=${INPUT_USER_NAME} \
  --dbname=${INPUT_DBNAME} \
  --private-key-path=/root/.snowsql/rsa_key.p8 \
  --config /config
```

This runs as expected and returns the query result. But it uses a small setting when querying Snowflake. Is there a way to adjust this, e.g. large?

And for odbc:

```
[snowflake]
Description=SnowflakeDB
Driver=SnowflakeDSIIDriver
Locale=en-US
SERVER=<ourorg>.us-east-1.snowflakecomputing.com
PORT=443
SSL=on
ACCOUNT=<ourorg>.us-east-1
# change to your snowflake user_name
UID=MY_NAME
# change to /home/<your-home>/keys/rsa_key.p8
PRIV_KEY_FILE=/home/my_name/keys/rsa_key.p8
# change "blahblah' to the passphrase you set for your private key in step 1.c
PRIV_KEY_FILE_PWD=blahblah
AUTHENTICATOR=SNOWFLAKE_JWT
```

And then I connect with (`R`)

```
sfconn <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = 'snowflake', warehouse = 'DATA_SCIENCE_WH_L', 
                         database = 'ourorg', role='DATA_SCIENCE_FULL')
```

This connects fine and I'm able to query Snowflake using odbc client. The query is run with the 'large' settings. Is it possible to adjust this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By 'size' do you mean the virtual warehouse size? Are you specifying the warehouse when connecting via SnowSQL or defaulting to one that is sized as small?  I see on the ODBC line that you are using a warehouse name of DATA_SCIENCE_WH_L while you are not listing a warehouse (or role) on the SnowSQL connection string.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info. When I login to Snowflake and click on history there's a field 'Size' currently with values of small or large, reflecting my previous queries. I'm not sure what this field is actually called other than just 'size'?!

Comment: Welp, this gave me th info I needed for adjusting odbc, I looked in the UI for other warehouses and found one DATA_SCIENCE_WH_2XL which is an extra large WH. Hopefully this speeds things up.

Comment: Accepting because this nudges me to the info I need. With SnowSQL on this documentation page seems I just need to specify warehouse https://dwgeek.com/snowsql-command-line-options-and-examples.html/

Comment: Just keep in mind that a larger warehouse will not _always_ speed up your queries - your local admin can assist with tuning approaches.  Some tuning suggestions are listed [here](https://medium.com/@jryan999/top-3-snowflake-performance-tuning-tactics-894c573731d2).